# How to stop browser from asking to save email and password in sign up form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a sign up form in PHP. Every time I click on sign up button the browser asks to save the email and password. How can I stop this?

Comment: This is generally a browser feature, not a php/html feature.

Comment: It's possible (though I haven't tested it) that if you use JavaScript to collect text from inputs (which are not part of a form) and then post by AJAX and do a client-side redirect on success (if necessary), to not trigger this functionality, though it seems like a huge workaround for something which is meant to be there to benefit user experience.

Comment: As you are only asking/talking about yourself: You can easily stop it during development by changing the preferences of your personal browser settings - just disable "Rememer passwords" or "Ask for saving passwords" or "Use Autofill on forms" or whatever this functionallity is called in your browser. ;-) In case you are asking in general to disable this function for your visitors: Don't change the default browser behaviour. Some people might need this feature for a good reason. Disabling it would be as bad as disabling the right mouse click to prevent opening the context menu...

Answer (score 2):

As of April 2016, this is browser-level behaviour and the user's reponsibility to control.

Two things you can do are:

1. You can inform the user on how to prevent this message displaying and
2. File a complaint with the browser devleopment team to urge them to change the behaviour. If enough people want it changed then it will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autocomplete="off" on input fields like this

```
   <input type="text" name="Username" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="password" name="Password" autocomplete="off">
```

or on the form tag. May not work on all browsers.

Please refer to http://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete on supported browsers.

Comment: _if a site sets autocomplete="off" [...], then the browser will still offer to remember this login. [...]. This is the behavior in Firefox (since version 38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since version 11)_ **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)**

Comment: @Przemek That's why I added the link to caniuse.com before, where you'll find exact the information you provided.

Comment: Your link to caniuse.com outlines which browsers support autocomplete functionality or ignore it. Offering to remember logins and passwords is something completly different.

Answer (score 0):

This code solves my issue. I have just add

> readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"

besides

> autocomplete="off"

And input should look like this

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" autocomplete="off" readonly 
    onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >

<input type="password" name="Password" autocomplete="off" readonly 
    onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >
```

Answer (score -2):

Add attribute **autocomplete="off"** in form tag

-----